# validate radio button

Tags: php, javascript

How to validate radio button through javascript?

```
Male <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />
female <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
document.getElementsByName('sex').value == 'male'
                   ^
```

[`Reference`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName)

[`one more`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-getelementsbyname)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, include jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    if (!$("input[@name='sex']:checked").val()) {
       alert('Nothing checked!');
        return false;
    }
    else {
      alert('A radio button is checked!');
    }
  });
});
```

Your html should look like this

```
<form method="post" id="form">
Male <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />
female <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Remember to include the jQuery api's

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i want to do it via javascript

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for required validation:
Check the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language='javascript'>
   function submit_form(){
   var temp=document.getElementsByName("gender");       
   if(temp[0].checked == true || temp[1].checked == true )
   { 
      document.forms["f1"].submit();        
   }
   else
   {
    alert("Please Select a Gender");
   }
}
</script>
<body> 
 <form id="f1" action="custom.html" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>
<input type="button" id="s1" onclick="submit_form()" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you choose different `id` for radio button?

Comment: @Vamsi I know this basic thing :)

Comment: @diEcho then why did you ask "why you choose different id for radio button?" above